# How to find relation b/w two collections c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to find a relation of employe and manager b/w arrays.

my code like :

```
public static IEnumerable<LwCiPersonManagers> GetManagerInfo()
{
    var lstManagement = new List<LwCiPersonManagers>
    {
        new LwCiPersonManagers(1, FindPerson("He man").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("She Ra").LwCiPersonKey, true),
        new LwCiPersonManagers(2, FindPerson("Lion O").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("El Presidente").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(3, FindPerson("She Ra").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Lion O").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(4, FindPerson("Jimbo").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Bugs Bunny").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(5, FindPerson("Popeye").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Bugs Bunny").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(6, FindPerson("Billy Bob").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Popeye").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(7, FindPerson("Larry").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Popeye").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(8, FindPerson("Moe").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Popeye").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(9, FindPerson("Curly").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Popeye").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(10, FindPerson("Alvin").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Minnie Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(11, FindPerson("Simon").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Minnie Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(12, FindPerson("Theodore").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Minnie Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(13, FindPerson("Minnie Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Daisy Duck").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(14, FindPerson("Daisy Duck").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("El Presidente").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(15, FindPerson("Donald Duck").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Daisy Duck").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(16, FindPerson("Goofy").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("Mickey Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, true), 
        new LwCiPersonManagers(17, FindPerson("Mickey Mouse").LwCiPersonKey, FindPerson("El Presidente").LwCiPersonKey, true)
    };

    return lstManagement;
}
```

how i can find the correct record just like something ...

```
private static LwCiPerson FindPerson(string nameToFind)
{
   LwCiPerson empFound = null;
   //Find the person within the collection returned by .ListPeople()

  return empFound;
}
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this (assuming `ListPeople()` is a method that returns a collection of people and they nave a property `Name`):

```
private static LwCiPerson FindPerson(string nameToFind)
{
    LwCiPerson empFound = ListPeople().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == nameToFind);
    return empFound;
}
```

Comment: this is returning null

Comment: actually i need a relationship b/w employe and manager the first function has all the mangers and in dropdown i am displaying employe so if the employe 1 selects the findperson method should need to findout all the manager which belongs to employe 1

Comment: Can you specify the schema of your objects and through which property are they related?

Comment: How can you give me an example ?

Comment: What are the properties of your classes that represent a manager and an employee and what is the name of the property that represents the relation between them. As an example you could have a class called `Employee` with properties `Name` and `ManagerId`. The property `ManagerId` is used to establish the relation between `Employee` and `Manager`. What are those properties in your case?